# Weird AngularJS/IE issue with dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm experiencing a strange issue with a form I'm currently working on with AngularJS. The problem does not happen in Chrome or Firefox.

Essentially, I've created a form that allows you to choose objects. The objects could be servers, folders, whatever. After choosing these objects, they are separated into panels that can be collapsed. The panel has the name of the object, a button to add users and a button to remove the object. When first visiting this page there is no problem. I can add users and remove objects.

The problem happens when I go to add a bunch of users. A modal window opens, and I can choose to add any number of users to either one object or all the objects. If I choose to add enough users that it causes the content on the page to scroll vertically, none of panels or buttons off the page can be interacted with. If I interact with one of the panels that still works, it fixes the rest of the page. If I resize the browser or go to developer mode that fixes it too.

Again, this doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox. Keep in mind all the content is there visually, it just can't be interacted with. Only the content that was visible to begin with can be interacted with.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

edit: I've actually tracked down the issue to the CSS styling. Because I've got my html set to 100% height for page design, it's causing the issue that anything that scrolls past that point in IE is not functioning properly. If I remove the height: 100% from the html tag it works fine. Now I guess I need to find a way to redesign the site so that I'm able to do what I'm wanting without that setting.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It is hard to diagnose your problem because we don't know how to reproduce it. Perhaps you can assemble a minimal test case at jsfiddle.com so people can have a clue.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you making calls to the api while "adding objects"?

Comment: I'll see about trying to create a test case. It's just a lot of parts so it would take time doing so. The objects themselves are just JS arrays. Like I said, the data itself is showing up just fine it's just that when the page scrolls vertically, the elements within those panels no longer respond to events at all. Tooltips don't show up. Can't click on them. Even though they worked perfectly fine before being scrolled off the screen.